# why の goes with other particles except に?

Tags: grammar, particles, particle-の

I have seen の joining with で, と, へ and others to form a relative clause, but never with に, why is that? Logically, shouldn't it be possible as well? For example 彼女への手紙, how do you say it but with に? is it just 彼女に手紙? but then I feel like it's missing a verb here.

Comment: Are you asking why にの isn't a thing?  Because のに definitely is.

Comment: @istrasci Yes, you can tell by my example

Comment: Something like 彼女への手紙 doesn't have a relative clause. Where is the verb? Here "adjectival phrase" is better.

Comment: Different functions. Generally の is used for possessions and descriptions. For example, "John's pizza", "humans of New York" and "chicken soup" have a lot in common. We are trying to say that one unit somehow belongs to another, either being in physical possession or borrowing some descriptive quality. All 3 are also expressed using the same の in Japanese, thus to make it less ambiguous it's combined with other particles like へ/から (directions). There is no place for に, because に is a core argument for a verb and won't help much. Notice that direction に is possible only with directive verbs.